# Django Populate ManyToMany according to a ChoiceField selection within a ModelForm

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-queryset

I have a class with a ManyToMany relationship, which I want to use to create a control panel for an app:

```
class ControlPanel(models.Model):
    viewtype = models.CharField("view type", max_length=32, unique=True)    
    choice1 = models.ManyToManyField(Choice1, null=True)
    choice2 = models.ManyToManyField(Choice2, null=True)
    choice3 = models.ManyToManyField(Choice3, null=True)
```

where `Choice1`, `Choice2` and `Choice3` are options hat I want to render as checkboxes. `controlpanel_choice1`, `controlpanel_choice2` and `controlpanel_choice3` are tables for the M2M relation with `Choice1`, `Choice2` and `Choice3` option choices. Thus depending on viewtype id, the choices set may be different (or even non existent) for each of `Choice*` sets.

I created a form from this ControlPanel class to generate my control panel:

```
class ControlPanelForm(ModelForm):
    viewtype = forms.ChoiceField(choices = ControlPanel.objects.values_list('id','view'))
    choice1 = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=Choice1.objects.all())
    choice2 = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=Choice2.objects.all())
    choice3 = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=Choice3.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = ControlPanel
```

This displays the 3 choice* field fine. However, it does not restrict the choices to each viewtype options, as my queryset displays `.objects.all()` for each `choice*` field. Furthermore, this displays the object address, not the name field of each Choice*.
How can I do this? I need to have the Choice* displayed for both a bound and unbound form. Do I need to build them in the constructor, checking if my form is valid and getting the current selected viewtype to build my querysets? Can I have this logic inside my `ControlPanel` class, and avoid programming this in my view function? I would appreciate some examples to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create a form that accepts an argument

```
class ControlPanelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ControlPanel
        widgets = {
            'choice1': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
            'choice2': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
            'choice3': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        viewtype = kwargs.pop('viewtype')
        super(ControlPanelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['choice1'].queryset = Choice1.objects.filter( ... )
        self.fields['choice2'].queryset = Choice2.objects.filter( ... )
        self.fields['choice3'].queryset = Choice3.objects.filter( ... )
```

As you can see I've passed `viewtype` as a positional argument to the init of the form, now you can use that to create querysets with a `filter()` instead of using `all()`.

Also, when using a `ModelForm`, there's no need to declare the form fields again. Should you need to change the widget of any of the fields, using the `widgets` option of the `Meta` class would seem more appropriate.

Now, to use this form in your view, just pass the `viewtype` in as a positional argument.

```
viewtype = request.POST['viewtype']
form = ControlPanelForm(viewtype=viewtype)
```

All you have to do now is put this in a view and call it, each time passing in a different `viewtype`.

Comment: Hi,Many thanks for these pointers, very useful. If I want to have a default value for viewtype (when having an unbound form), should I pass this value in the view, or can I declare it in the ControlPanelForm class?

Comment: I have tried your advice and start to see the light! If I understand well, there is no way to access the selected value of the widget within the ModelForm instance (?) and thus I have to pass it as a positional argument. I also understand that viewtype=kwargs.pop('viewtype') just removes an non-valid argument from the __init__ of the ModelForm. Furthermore, I could use another name (such as viewnb) for popping the argument and use this variable for my filters. It is just convenient to keep all the same name. Is this correct?

Comment: Thus, for a default view value, I just tested that request.POST.has_key('viewtype'). If not, then the form is instanciated with default value and I pass viewtype={'viewtype':'1'} in the constructor, '1' being my default value when the form is created (and I can use request.method=='POST' test if the page with the form is accessed without POST at all).

Comment: When you say the you've tested the request to see if it contains a `viewtype` does this mean every time the user selects a viewtype the whole page refreshes?

Comment: No, I have not experimented the AJAX part yet if this is what you mean. The user needs to submit the new form after he changes the viewtype. This I will implement it later.

Comment: 1. The only way to have access to the request object within your form is to pass it through your view. 2. You can name `viewtype` anything, keeping the same name is more readable. 3. Yes, testing if `viewtype` exists within `request.POST` and switching to a defalut, if not present, is a good idea.

Comment: This is almost working, except I ran into trouble when changing viewtype. For instance, let's say I select viewtype 1, which shows choice1 queryset as a CheckboxselectionMultiple(). Then if I select viewtype2 and Submit, then POST contains (e.g.) '{'choice1':[1,2]}. If viewtype2 does not contain these choice1, then I get validation errors. Ideally, when chaging viewtype (and only viewtype), then the form should be reset to initial values. How can I achieve this? Can I detect if the field has changed?

Comment: It's better if changing viewtype would have its own submission trigger. Submit onChange of viewtype using JS.

Comment: Yes, I think I should use client side to filter out display choices. I will experiment with Javascript soon to try to obtain the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Just a follow-up to this problem: I realised this is more logical to implement such kind of feature on the client side, using javascript/jQuery. Indeed, due to the non persistent aspect of HTMl, it is very awkward and error prone to have such logic on the server side. I had a lot less trouble learning basic jQuery and have a nice way to hide/show options and results on the browser side.